# How is spock calling this function in this test?

Tags: groovy, spock, jenkins-groovy

I'm going through this example but something about it is very confusing to me: https://www.testcookbook.com/book/groovy/jenkins/intro-testing-job-dsl.html

In this test, how/what is executing `getJobFiles()`? I don't see it being called anywhere. Is there some magic with `jobFiles`? Is specifying `jobFiles` somehow calling getJobFiles?

```
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement
import org.junit.ClassRule
import org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class JobScriptsSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    @ClassRule
    JenkinsRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule()

    @Unroll
    def 'test script #file.name'(File file) {
        given:
        def jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))

        when:
        new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).runScript(file.text)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        where:
        file << jobFiles
    }

    static List<File> getJobFiles() {
        List<File> files = []
        new File('jobs').eachFileRecurse {
            if (it.name.endsWith('.groovy')) {
                files << it
            }
        }
        files
    }
}
```

### Edit

It seems like jobFiles does call getJobFiles() but I don't understand how. Is this a groovy or spock feature? I've been trying to research this but can finding anything explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard Groovy functionality. You can abbreviate any getter call like

```
def file = new File("sarek-test-parent/sarek-test-common/src/main/java")
println file.name          // getName()
println file.parent        // getParent()
println file.absolutePath  // getAbsolutePath()
println file.directory     // isDirectory()
```

```
java
sarek-test-parent\sarek-test-common\src\main
C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\Sarek\sarek-test-parent\sarek-test-common\src\main\java
true
```

The same works for setters:

```
new Person().name = "John"      // setName("John")
new Person().zipCode = "12345"  // setZipCode("12345")
```

Actually the second link provided by *jaco0646* explains it, just his mixing up this simple fact with data providers clouds the explanation.

Comment: so getJobFiles is a static class method? by calling `jobFiles` its calling `JobScriptsSpec.getJobFiles()`?

Comment: Yes, this works both with static and instance methods names like setters or getters.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

When Groovy determines that `jobFiles` does not refer to any existing variable, it considers the name as a  Groovy [property](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters), which then allows it to take advantage of the shortcut notation for accessing properties.

Comment: There is nothing Spock does, this is standard Groovy.